# Doubt about how to do these basic subtraction exercises

Tags: xlop

I would appreciate it too much if someone could help me generate this type of subtraction exercises. I use the xlop package but I don't know if it is possible for me to do that type of exercise.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\def\xyz#1{{\fboxsep-.5pt\fbox{\phantom{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
\opadd[operandstyle.2=\xyz]{457}{127} \qquad
\opadd[operandstyle.1.3=\xyz,
operandstyle.2.2=\xyz]
{457}{127}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]